# Script to get info from multiple servers

Tags: bash, expect, remote-access

I want to collect info from a number of servers whether their grub.conf contains the "elevator" parameter or not.

Now, password-less key authentication is something I can not do as of now. I am okay with specifying password in script.

Can someone please help me achieving this?

This is what I did:

```
#!/bin/bash

GRUB="/etc/grub.conf"
_pair="$(</home/wadhwaso/login.txt)"
Server_info="/tmp/server_info"
for e in $_pair
do
             # extract user and ips for each $e in $_pair
        IFS='@'
        set -- $e
        _user="$1"
        _ip="$2"

        sleep 2
        echo "Connecting to server '${_ip}' via SSH..."
        ssh ${_user}@${_ip} "sudo grep -q "elevator=noop" "$GRUB" >/dev/null"
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Present on ${_ip}" | tee -a "${Server_info}"
        else
        echo "not present on ${_ip}" | tee -a "${Server_info}"
        fi
done
```

I don't want to give password every time, and as password-less authentication is not present in my environment and will not be possible, I have to pass the password in script itself which really doesn't bother me, I can do that. I know it could be done through expect but I messed everything every time I tried using it.

I tried using expect the way it was told in 1st answer but I failed.

Comment: use public and private key auth? then just read the server list from a file using a while loop.

Comment: I wish I could do key auth Jason, but that wont happen ..

and I tried making my script read server names from a file but I cant figure out why it is failing to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "expect" tool sounds perfect for what you need: http://expect.sourceforge.net/

To install expect (on ubuntu, for example), do:

```
sudo apt-get install expect
```

Here's a code snippet showing you how to use expect as part of a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

IP="111.111.11.1"
login="root"
password="some_password"
dest_dir="/etc/"

expect_sh=$(expect -c "
    spawn ssh $login@$IP
    expect \"password:\"
    send \"$password\r\"
    expect \"#\"
    send \"cd $dest_dir\r\"
    expect \"#\"
    send \"chmod +x $server_side_script"
    expect \"#\"
    send \"./$server_side_script\r\"
    expect \"#\"
    send \"cd /lib\r\"
    send \"cat $file_count\r\" 
    expect \"#\"
    send \"exit\r\"
")

echo "$expect_sh"
```

Alternatively, you can put the logic in a separate expect script for neater syntax and source it from your bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set login "root"
set addr "111.111.1.1"
set pw "root"

spawn ssh $login@$addr
expect "$login@$addr\'s password:"
send "$pw\r"
expect "#"
send "cd /etc\r"
# Then other things you need to do
```

As for the "3rd thing" with RSA key fingerprint: SSH will warn you if connecting to a host you haven't seen before (because of possibility of man-in-the-middle attacks), theoretically you should verify that the fingerprint matches what you anticipate it to be to verify that the host is who the host claims to be.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: I tried using expect like you said but I am doing something wrong. I edited my script, can you integrate expect in my script for me ?

p.s. I am using RHEL 5.7 tikanga